# RTC Jazz Build engine abondons all builds

Tags: build, rtc, jazz

Today my build eninge (RTC/Jazz build engine) makes trouble - i start a build and it abondons the build:

```
This build has been automatically abandoned by the build engine 'vis1adaBuildEngine'.
This can happen if the build engine stops while it is processing a build, or if it fails     to communicate with the server (e.g. due to the server crashing, or a network     break).
As a result, the build is left in the in-progress state.

Such builds are automatically abandoned for the following reasons:
1. When the build engine is restarted, new builds will be processed, however the old     builds would otherwise remain in the in-progress state indefinitely.
2. As a result the build engine would appear as busy when it is not.
```

i cant tell why it's not working anymore - i have another build engine running on my build server and this works fine - also other build definitions work on the 'buggy' build engine fine, so what could be the reason?

The build definition itself hasn't been changed for a longer period of time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And don't have much information on this, except for those two threads:

- [Unable to "complete" build activity](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/71941/unable-to-quotcompletequot-build-activity):

> This solved my problem: delete the build engine and create it again. Created two build engines separated, one for using it with Jenkins in a server and other one for other server.

- "[Build Engine not starting correctly and requests abandoned](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/76876/build-engine-not-starting-correctly-and-requests-abandoned)"

> Another cause that gives this error message is when there are 2 build engines running with the same Id. It can occur easily when you are cloning VM

Both could be relevant considering:

> i have another build engine running on my build serve

**THANKS** for helping me out:

[image]

Comment: i think the answer from "Build Engine not starting correctly and requests abandoned" from Philippe Kaplan might be a reason: we have changed the IP of our VM-Build Server... i'll check my IT-Service.. i'll be right back...

Comment: HELP - i stopped my BuildEngines on the build server but ***SURPRISE*** the build engine is still running!!!

Comment: @MartinFrank strage. Any way to kill the process?

Comment: i've appended my build jobs in your answer - i could restart the server and after that all worked out fine...

Comment: @MartinFrank great! Restarting the server isn't ideal, but at least it works now.